# Will wireless isolation/AP isolation protect from KRACK?

Tags: network, wireless, krack, isolation

Will using AP isolation on an Access Point protect connected clients from the KRACK vulnerability on that network?

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

Wireless/client/AP isolation only provides a means of isolating one wireless client from another. It has no bearing on how 802.11 encryption works or how the WPA2 handshake takes place.

Since KRACK attacks the WPA2 handshake and compromises the encryption between a client device and the access point, it really doesn't care if the wireless client can reach another wireless client.

Comment: Can it at least limit the damage/risk to only one device at a time (If one device is compromised, could the others be protected by isolation at least until they are compromised too, one by one?)?

Comment: @Daniel, it can't limit the damage/risk from KRACK. KRACK doesn't grant access to the network or give control of a client device with a compromised connection. Wireless/client/AP isolation can help to do exactly as you describe if a client device is compromised by other exploits or malicious code (which could be introduced by a KRACK MitM attack or countless other attack vectors). However this is not protection from KRACK.